# AutoHotkey script only works when this window is open

Tags: autohotkey, pen

Autohotkey script only works when I have this window open (please see screenshot).  If I minimise it, it does not work.  I have the H visible in the tray.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

My script to use with Windows Pen is simply:

#F20::Run OneNote ; Single click, Open OneNote

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? OneNote is already running in either case, right? Are you just trying to switch to it? Did you try mapping the pen click to a keyboard shortcut? OneNote has several default new note `win+n` or quick note `win+alt+n` shortcuts and one to open OneNote `win+shift+n` that may work.

Answer (score -3):

if your keyboard has a f20 key

#F20::Run `C:\Windows\write.exe`

Would run wordpad.

Supply the path where OneNote is located.

#F20::Run path\OneNote